# Disable customerrors for asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I know for asp.net you would use `<customErrors mode="Off" />`, but I that doesn't work for asp classic. I want to debug the asp file. How do I fix this?

Comment: You mean sending full error message for each error that happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:asp -scriptErrorSentToBrowser:false
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable server side debugging in the IIS settings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241732(v=vs.80).aspx